# how to overwrite / use cookies in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrap http://www.3andena.com/, this web site starts first in Arabic, and it stores the language settings in cookies. If you tried to access the language version directly through URL (http://www.3andena.com/home.php?sl=en), it makes a problem and return server error.

So, I want to set the cookie value "store_language" to "en", then start scrap the website using this cookie values.

I'm using CrawlSpider with a couple of Rules.

here's the code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy import log
from bkam.items import Product
from scrapy.http import Request
import re

class AndenaSpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "andena"
  domain_name = "3andena.com"
  start_urls = ["http://www.3andena.com/Kettles/?objects_per_page=10"]

  product_urls = []

  rules = (
     # The following rule is for pagination
     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'\?page=\d+$'),), follow=True),
     # The following rule is for produt details
     Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[contains(@class, "products-dialog")]//table//tr[contains(@class, "product-name-row")]/td'), unique=True), callback='parse_product', follow=True),
     )

  def start_requests(self):
    yield Request('http://3andena.com/home.php?sl=en', cookies={'store_language':'en'})

    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_category)


  def parse_category(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    self.product_urls.extend(hxs.select('//td[contains(@class, "product-cell")]/a/@href').extract())

    for product in self.product_urls:
        yield Request(product, callback=self.parse_product)  


  def parse_product(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    items = []
    item = Product()

    '''
    some parsing
    '''

    items.append(item)
    return items

SPIDER = AndenaSpider()
```

Here's the log :

```
2012-05-30 19:27:13+0000 [andena] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.3andena.com/home.php?sl=en&xid_479d9=97656c0c5837f87b8c479be7c6621098> from <GET http://3andena.com/home.php?sl=en>
2012-05-30 19:27:14+0000 [andena] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.3andena.com/home.php?sl=en&xid_479d9=97656c0c5837f87b8c479be7c6621098> from <GET http://www.3andena.com/home.php?sl=en&xid_479d9=97656c0c5837f87b8c479be7c6621098>
2012-05-30 19:27:14+0000 [andena] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.3andena.com/Kettles/?objects_per_page=10> (referer: None)
2012-05-30 19:27:15+0000 [andena] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.3andena.com/B-and-D-Concealed-coil-pan-kettle-JC-62.html> (referer: http://www.3andena.com/Kettles/?objects_per_page=10)
```

Answer (score 13):

modify your codes as below:

```
def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, cookies={'store_language':'en'}, callback=self.parse_category)
```

Scrapy.Request object accepts optional `cookies` keyword argument, [see documentation here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response)

Answer (score 10):

This is how I do it as of Scrapy 0.24.6:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

    ...

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        request = super(MySpider, self).make_requests_from_url(url)
        request.cookies['foo'] = 'bar'
        return request
```

Scrapy calls `make_requests_from_url` with the URLs in the `start_urls` attribute of the spider. What the code above is doing is letting the default implementation create the request and then adding a `foo` cookie that has the value `bar`. (Or changing the cookie to the value `bar` if it so happens, against all odds, that there is already a `foo` cookie on the request produced by the default implementation.)

In case you wonder what happens with requests that are *not* created from `start_urls`, let me add that Scrapy's cookie middleware will remember the cookie set with the code above and set it on all future requests that share the same domain as the request on which you explicitly added your cookie.

Comment: I would like to do something like this but make_requests_from_url  has been removed from scrapy

Answer (score 4):

Straight from the [Scrapy documentation for Requests and Responses.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response)

You'll need something like this

```
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.3andena.com", cookies={'store_language':'en'})
```

Comment: I tried this already before posting my question, but it doesn't work

Comment: I just noticed that the website stores the language value in `'store_language'` and not in `'store_lang'`. I've edited the original answer. Accept if it works.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. And added the log to my question.
Thanks a lot for keeping on support BTW